# iOS - TableViewController e SWRevealViewController for menu

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

In my tableview I inserted a barbutton item inside the Navigation Controller as in the photo Which at the pressure must open a side menu

[image]

The problem is that I do not open any menus!
I follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXCHDP9V3aM&t=188s

It looks like the tableview does not recognize the button pressure .. what can I do?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: show your button action code

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad yep, one moment

Comment: add some code @user2324946

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad http://imgur.com/Yryg2nB

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik http://imgur.com/Yryg2nB

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre http://imgur.com/Yryg2nB

Comment: @user2324946 add debugger at `if (self.revealViewController() != nil)` to find if condition satisfying  or not

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre the debugger doesn't enter into the if condition..why?!

Comment: you need to set `SWRevealViewController` as  rootViewController. I think you have login view then you are pushing to tabView.

Comment: The most convenient to be a reason for the revealViewController to be nil is you didn't connect segues correctly in stroyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient to be a reason for the revealViewController to be nil is you didn't connect segues correctly in stroyboard.

If TabViewController is not your storyboard entry point then add this code in AppDelegate.
AppDelegate :

```
if (userDefaults.object(forKey:"user") != nil) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Or If you are presenting the TabViewController for other viewController then use this code to present TabViewController.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let main = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") //SWRevealViewController
self.present(main, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Update :

1. You need to separate loginViewController and TabViewController as in the below image.(No segue between both)

[image]

2. Add SWRevealViewController and Menu screen tableview.
3. Next, control-drag from SWRevealViewController to the Menu view controller. After releasing the button, you will see a context menu for segue selection. In this case, select “reveal view controller set segue”. This defines a custom segue “SWRevealViewControllerSetSegue”. Select the segue and change its identifier to “sw_rear” under the Identity inspector. By setting the identifier, you tell SWRevealViewController that the menu view controller is the rear view controller. In this case, the sidebar menu will be hidden behind a content view controller.
4. Next, repeat the same procedures to connect SWRevealViewController with the navigation controller of the news view controller. Again, select “reveal view controller set segue” when prompted. Set the identifier of the segue to “sw_front”. This tells the SWRevealViewController that the navigation controller is the front view controller.
5. same with tableview controller to main view controller just select segue as reveal view controller push.
6. Add this code in all tabs.

   ```
   if (self.revealViewController() != nil) {
   menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
   menuButton.action =  #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
   self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
   }
   ```
7. After Login Jump to TabViewController use this code.

   ```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let main = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") //SWRevealViewController
   self.present(main, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```
8. After login : To skip login view add this check in AppDelegate :
   AppDelegate :

   ```
   if (userDefaults.object(forKey:"user") != nil) {
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   }
   ```

Comment: I do not understand what to do and what to change
 :(

Comment: @Taprolano How do you presenting TabView ?

Comment: @Taprolano you are doing wrong bro. 1. login screen then TabView 2. You need to create RevealViewController and menu screen as shown in the youtube video.

Comment: @Taprolano share link of video is good. You just need to follow every step or check my update part. It will help you achieve your goal.