# iOS Application with TabBar and SlideMenu

Tags: swift, tabbar

I want to have both a navigation menu(slide menu) and tabbar throughout my application. I am using the library SWReveal. I have managed to get both but at the moment my layout seems rather silly. Please see image attached.[image: Image of my storyboard showing how the tab view controller creates a tab for each swrevealviewcontroller]

I could only add a tabbar when I go through each SWRevealviewcontroller. I can't seem to give the tab bar controller the swrevealcontrollerview so that it populates all further views with my slide menu. Do I really have to create the SWReveal Controller and its corresponding table view every time I have a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not require to create SWRevealController for every tabs. You can create SWRevealController and add to `UItabViewController`. It will work for all tabs you created.**

You can do similar to my project :

Step 1 : Create UIViewController with class `SWRevealViewController`.

Step 2 : Create UITableViewController and make `SWRevealViewController`  storyboard segue with identifier `sw_rear`.

Step 3 : Create UITabViewController and make `SWRevealViewController`  storyboard segue with identifier `sw_front`

[image]

And you can refer below link where I answered same time of question with detailed explanation :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44780371/5094664

Answer (score 1):

In my past project i also used SWRevielViewController. I faced lot of orientation problems in it. As per your requirement it's better to handle things using containerView. 
1. Create ParentController with ContainerView. 
2. Make parentcontroller tab bar and manage showing tab index and container view childs using your ui navigation.

For your reference you can see this repo - https://github.com/amrittrivedir/CustomTabBar

For swift you can have this demo - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1faFagqDZwpfRN7lzDPknQAeWGvhx3271